# Accessing Local Service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-8.5

Hope you can help.

We have a web application (.NET 2.0) that has some custom code that is used to poke a windows service when a file is uploaded. We issue a command using the following code:

```
  Dim serviceName As String = "Processor Service 1.0"
  sc = New ServiceController(serviceName)
  sc.ExecuteCommand(200)
```

Running this code in a standalone app works fine but when running through website throws an access denied error. Code works fine in IIS 6.

We are using an application pool with a user and is in Admin group. I figure it's something to do with IIS but now sure what.

Hoping you guys can help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the source code / modification rights for the windows service itself? I would be tempted to make the service use a `FileSystemWatcher` to look for newly uploaded files on its own, then you don't need to poke it anyway. It also decouples the two things a little bit so in the future it's easier to maintain.

Comment: You could try giving `IIS APPPOOL\NameOfYourPool` some access to the `Processor Service 1.0`.  For that you have to look into `sc.exe sdset`, it's not super easy to figure out the syntax but it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions that are needed to interact with local services are pretty high.  Your asp.net app is likely running as anonymous (local account IUSR), or the "application pool identity".  You would have setup your app in IIS (app pool) to use a different account with greater permissions.

In IIS Admin, under the section "IIS", "Authentication", you need to enable a stronger authentication method.  If "Anonymous Authentication" is the only one enabled, then check the settings "Edit" to see if it is running as IUSR or "Application pool identity".  This is where you determine, or set, the account (and permission set) that your ASP.NET app is using.

I feel that I should strongly warn against elevating the permissions for IIS and anonymous users.  This would create a very dangerous back-door into your system. The suggestion from bgs264 is a very good one: make a separate service (or scheduled process) that watches for file uploads, or modify the existing service to use the file-watcher to monitor for uploaded files.  It could run under a higher permission set and would be much more isolated from your IIS.  Granting admin permissions to IIS or its app pools, is just like begging for trouble.

Comment: Hi Guys. Apologies for only getting back now. Thank you to tgolisch for pointing me in the right direction. When I Edited "Anonymous Authentication settings it was set to use IUSR and not Application Pool Identity. Changing this resolved the issue. We are happy to go with that for now as that is how the old configuration was working.